# Kotlin class parameter value between abstract class and its concrete class

Tags: kotlin

I have a problem understanding how class parameter value behaves between abstract/concrete classes.

Abstract class example:

```
abstract class A {

   init {
       initStuff()
   }

   fun initStuff() {
       additionalInit()
   }

   abstract fun additionalInit()
}
```

Concrete class example:

```
class B(val exParam: Int): A {

    init {
       println("$exParam") // This would give expected value.
    }

    override fun additionalInit() {
       println("$exParam") // Always zero even if exParam value is set.
    }
}
```

My question is that based on my understanding, I want to call `B(1000)` and expect both `println` inside the B class to print `1000` but this was not the case so my understanding is clearly off here so anyone can light me to the right understanding?

Comment: You use `class B(val exParam : Int) : A() {` right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note what you are using here is an anti-pattern, i.e. calling a method from the constructor which is overridable by subclasses and that for the very reason you now realise as an unexpected behaviour.

Now what's happening here: before you can even initialize `B` `A` needs to be constructed first. So the constructors and `init` of `A` get called first. But the variable for `B` is not assigned yet at that very moment. So that's why we still have that `0` there. Even if you set a default value of, lets say `-1` (i.e. `val exParam : Int = -1`), you will see rather `0` here as output.

Summarizing: never ever call overridable functions in a constructor or init... Read more about it here: [What's wrong with overridable method calls in constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404301/whats-wrong-with-overridable-method-calls-in-constructors)

Comment: Awesome! I knew it.

Answer (score 2):

inheritance here works just like in Java. If you were to translate your construct into Java code, it would look something like this:

```
abstract class A {

    public A() {
        additionalInit();
    }

    abstract void additionalInit();

}

class B extends A {

    private int exParam;

    public B(int exParam) {
        // You can see here that this.exParam is initialized AFTER you're calling the super constructor
        super();
        this.exParam = exParam;
    }

    // getters and setters

}
```

Your IDE should give you a warning if you are trying to call abstract function from the init block because of this.

Comment: this clears thing up. But I had to mark @Roland answer here.